# Battery State Indicator LEDs in Wireless Charging

Tags: led, battery-charging, transmitter, receiver, wireless-charging

I am working on a custom wireless charging System. I am using the following ICs
**Transmitter IC**: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6992-1-6992-2-6992-3-6992-4.pdf
**Receiver IC**: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC4126.pdf
In circuit designing I took help from Demo Kit DC2663A-KIT: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/DC2663A-KIT.pdf

I want LED indicator LEDs that will tell me the different charging states of LEDs( Charging is full, Charging is on, Not charging etc.)
The receiver PCB has a LED that can show us these states of charging. But I want to use the Charging states indicator circuit on Transmitter PCB not the receiver PCB. Since both PCBs wont have any physical connection so I am unable to figure out how can I implement this indicator circuit of transmitter PCB.[image: Receiver PCB]
[image: Transmitter Schematic]

Comment: does anyone has any solution for this problem?